# Azure function write to file

Tags: azure-functions

I have created a Azure function. Purpose of that function is to write the message passed as parameter to a file.

I cannot use Azure App insights. Accessing the DB storage will slow the process. Those functions would be called from different programs written in react and hosted in SharePoint

Example

> https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Function1?code=xxxx&message=ThisIsTest

function1 will write message "ThisIsTest" but my issue is I am not able to retain the text file hosted with function 1 at location

> C:\home\site\wwwroot\Function1
> Folder "CustomMsg >> TestFile.txt"

but every time I publish the function, CustomMsg folder disappears. I don't want to Copy always option or Copy when new because this location would be accessible to other apps as well to do the changes.

Any suggestion please ?

Comment: Why not consider a database as storage ?

Comment: No DB as storage. I need to save in Text file using Azure function

Answer (score 1):

Your best choice will be to write the file to storage instead of to the drive since, as you've noticed, the wwwroot folder is overwritten with each deployment. As long as the volume on the function app is low you can use the storage account that is used for the function app, especially if you aren't using any durable functions. In many cases, the Blob output binding would be sufficient to do this with a minimum of code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=csharp.

If you are on a Linux host, you can mount a file share as a drive that will provide you with persistent storage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/storage-considerations

Comment: Thank you for the reply but as I mentioned , 
The idea is to call Azure function is to write short messages to the text file. It is more like logs. I cannot use Azure App insights. Accessing the DB storage will slow the process. Those functions would be called from different programs written in react and hosted in SharePoint.

Comment: The recommended way to handle logging outside of App Insights/Log Analytics is Blob storage. This is by writing files, not a database. Your minimum ingress speed is 5 Gbps and as long as you put your storage account in the same region, network  transit time will be tiny.

Something to consider here about performance is that by writing to the Function's file system, you are writing to storage the same as if you wrote to Blob store explicitly.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking into the Blob storage now. Thanks for giving me the direction. I haven't worked in Azure function with storage before.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to persist anything after you (re) deploy the code as you will be overwriting the existing resource.

If **stateless** write and read from files works for you, then try the following:

```cs
private static void WriteToTempFile(string content)
{
        var path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "content.txt");
      
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path))
        {           
            writer.Write(content);
        }
}
```